# Is it possible to create a HTML style table in Windows Phone 7 XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, tabular

Is it possible to create a table similar to what can be done in HTML using XAML for Windows Phone 7?

I can do it by placing text blocks in certain positions but this isn't an idea solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a table similar to what can be done in HTML using XAML for Windows Phone 7?

Sure. [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) provides that abstraction. It's very powerful. Divide the grid using ColumnDefinition and RowDefinition. [Here is a complete example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745823.aspx).